# Group list inside dict using multiple keys in python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Here I'm given input JSON data. Anyone help me to solve expected result below format.
I'm trying to solve but I can't get expected result format.

```
sub_type_list = [
   {
    'name':'blood',
    'transaction_points':[
        {
            'point':'(1-10)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':''
        },
        {
            'point':'(10-20)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id': "423"
        },
        {
            'point':'(20-30)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':'1'
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    'name':'blood',
    'transaction_points':[
        {
            'point':'(1-10)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':'123'
        },
        {
            'point':'(10-20)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':''
        },
        {
            'point':'(20-30)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':''
        }       
    ]           
  },
  {
    'name':'body',
    'transaction_points':[
        {
            'point':'(1-10)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':''
        },
        {
            'point':'(10-20)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':'42'
        },
        {
            'point':'(20-30)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':'11'
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    'name':'blood',
    'transaction_points':[
        {
            'point':'(1-10)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':'87'
        },
        {
            'point':'(10-20)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':'50'
        },
        {
            'point':'(20-30)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':'25'
        }
    ]
  }
 ]
```

**Expected Result below**

```
 [{
'name': 'blood',
'transaction_points':[
  [
      { 'point': '(1-10)', 'value': '', 'symbol': '', 'service_id': ''},
      {'point': '(1-10)', 'value': '', 'symbol': '', 'service_id': '123'},
      { 'point': '(1-10)', 'value': '', 'symbol': '', 'service_id': '87'}       
],
[     
     {'point': '(10-20)', 'value': '', 'symbol': '', 'service_id': '423'},
     {'point': '(10-20)', 'value': '', 'symbol': '', 'service_id': ''},
     {'point': '(10-20)', 'value': '', 'symbol': '', 'service_id': '50'}    
],
 [
     {'point': '(20-30)', 'value': '', 'symbol': '', 'service_id': '1'},
     '{point': '(20-30)', 'value': '', 'symbol': '', 'service_id': ''},
     '{point': '(20-30)', 'value': '', 'symbol': '', 'service_id': '25'}
    
 ]
]
},{
'name': 'body',
'transaction_points':[
  [
     {'point': '(1-10)', 'value': '', 'symbol': '', 'service_id': ''}
    
],
[ 
    {'point': '(10-20)', 'value': '', 'symbol': '', 'service_id': '42'} 
],
 [
    {'point': '(20-30)', 'value': '', 'symbol': '', 'service_id': '11'}     
]
]
}
]
```

Here I'm using given below code and try to generate expected result

```
 result = dict()
 final_result = []
 for id, i in enumerate(sub_type_list):
     if result.get(i["name"]):
          result[i["name"]].extend(i["transaction_points"])
     else:
          result[i["name"]] = i["transaction_points"]
 for i in result.keys():
      final_result.append({"name": i, "transaction_points": result[i]})
```

**final_result list produce give below result but I want expected result above**

```
 [
 {
    'name':'blood',
    'transaction_points':[
        {
            'point':'(1-10)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':''
        },
        {
            'point':'(10-20)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':'423'
        },
        {
            'point':'(20-30)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':'1'
        },
        {
            'point':'(1-10)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':'123'
        },
        {
            'point':'(10-20)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':''
        },
        {
            'point':'(20-30)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':''
        },
        {
            'point':'(1-10)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':'87'
        },
        {
            'point':'(10-20)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':'50'
        },
        {
            'point':'(20-30)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':'25'
        }
    ]
},
{
    'name':'body',
    'transaction_points':[
        {
            'point':'(1-10)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':''
        },
        {
            'point':'(10-20)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':'42'
        },
        {
            'point':'(20-30)',
            'value':'',
            'symbol':'',
            'service_id':'11'
        }
      ]
    }
   ]
```

Comment: why do two of your dicts have name and transaction points and the other 2 dont? What formula are you using to get the last dict, the first 3 are grouped by points but the last one doesnt have an obvious grouping?

Comment: @Craicerjack yes I'm the begineer of python so I can't get expected result format can you help me to solve this

Comment: **Your expected result is wrong** and impossible - you can't have a dictionary or set containing a list. The opposite is possible. So either you haven't formatted your expected output correctly or you're trying something Python and JSON don't allow.

Comment: I _think_ OP wants a "list of lists of dicts". If OP had a better history of accepting answers, I'd post a solution.

Comment: @aneroid I updated my expected result is it possible means anyone help me?

Comment: @aneroid a dictionary can contain a list. ah I see what you mean.

Comment: @Craicerjack Not as a _key_. And if you look at his expected output structure in the [previous version/edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65790126/1): it's **set notation** containing a list. And in the [current version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65790126/2), it's a dict with repeating keys. While not a syntax error, it's clearly not what is actually "wanted". As I said above, he probably wants a "list of lists of dicts" for the 'transactions' of each 'name' group. I think you have high enough rep to provide a solution. (edit: I see your edit now, so you see too :-) )

Comment: @arunkumar Keys in dictionaries should be unique and dictionaries are unordered so  you cannot achieve your expected results the way you want them

Comment: @aneroid yeah I hadnt looked at the edit properly. My apologies

Comment: @Craicerjack It's all good . Unclear questions can be closed until clarified. :-) will delete this comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at [groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function of itertools library.

Comment: this doesnt answer the question and would be more suited as a comment

Comment: @Metallimax I used groupby() function also 
lab_data = [] 
for k, v in groupby(lab_sub_type_list, key=lambda x: x['name']):
      lab_data.append({"name": k, "transaction_points": list(v['transaction_points'])})
but I can't get expected result format

Comment: @arunkumar so you will have to do it manually.

Comment: @MetallimaX can you help me to get expected result format?